# Euler-Lagrange problem for electrostatic energy

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, lagrangian-formalism

The energy density of an electrostatic field is given by: $\epsilon E^2/2$. Expressing the electric field $E = ∇ψ$
in terms of the electrostatic potential ψ, find the governing equation for ψ if the total electrostatic
energy is to be minimized.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not clear enough. With the info we have, the solution looks so easy that we have no need to write the minimization problem using calculus of variations.

I'd say that energy density is non-negative, so that the minimum value of the total energy is zero, forcing $\mathbf{E} = 0$ in the whole domain, and thus the potential is uniform, constant in space, $\psi(\mathbf{x}) = \overline{\psi}$.

*If there is something more, please edit you question and I'll update my answer*